# PHP function Mail dont work

Tags: php, email, gmail

```
if (@mail('email@gmail.com', 'Email Works', '$text'))) 
{
    echo('<p>Mail sent successfully.</p>');
} 
else 
{
    echo('<p>Mail could not be sent.</p>');
}
```

The message "Mail sent successfully" is printed but i don't receive the email

Comment: Have you setup smtp setting in your server?

Comment: did you bother checking your mail server logs to see what happened after PHP handed off the email? REmember that PHP doesn't have **ANYTHING** to do with actual delivery. It hands the email over to the local mail server and then it's done.

Comment: Gmail have a very strict spam policies try with an other mail.

Answer (score 1):

Your email content is going to be literally $text with that code.

Try

```
if (mail('email@gmail.com', 'Email Works', $text)) {
    echo '<p>Mail sent successfully.</p>';
} 
else {
    echo '<p>Mail could not be sent.</p>';
}
```

Also, Check your email and php settings to ensure you can use the mail function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup a mail server? If not then setup one like Sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

That may be possible that you have not install mail server on your server.If you are using XAMPP then Setup mail setting on XAMPP in php.ini Ex. Authentication Username, Password.

Here is [link](http://thephpcode.blogspot.in/2009/03/setting-up-local-mail-smtp-pop3-imap.html) can help you to setting up smtp settings.

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below

```
if ($mail('email@gmail.com', 'Email Works', $text)) {
    echo('<p>Mail sent successfully.</p>');
} 
else {
    echo('<p>Mail could not be sent.</p>');
}
```

Comment: Providing copypasta is not a very good answer, a good answer explains itself.